FreshService API Request through PowerShell
I have a code that is supposed to update the Usage_type of a device from "permanent" to "Loaner" in FreshService using Put method. I also want to change the asset_state_24000430944 field from "In-Use" to "Retired". But when I try to run it, it is giving me a 403 Error message. The error message is:
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
At line:44 char:11

$Status = Invoke-RestMethod @Params -Body $body

      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand



**Here is my script:**

$APIKey = ''
$EncodedCredentials = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("$APIKey:X"))
$HTTPHeaders = @{
    Authorization = $EncodedCredentials
}

$URL = '.freshservice.com/api/v2/assets'
$assetId = "3367"

$Params = @{
    Method      = 'Put'
    Uri         = "$URL/$assetId"
    Headers     = $HTTPHeaders
    ContentType = 'application/json'
}

# Disable or Retire Asset
$body = @{
    name = "PostComputer"
    asset_type_id = 24000430949
    asset_tag = "ASSET-9999"
    impact = "low"
    usage_type = "Loaner"
    description = "13.3-inch (diagonal) LED-backlit glossy widescreen display,1440-by-900 resolution"
    location_id = $null
    agent_id = $null
    department_id = $null
    group_id = $null
    workspace_id = 2
    assigned_on = "2014-07-26T12:25:04+05:30"
    type_fields = @{
        product_24000430944 = 24000109875
        cost_24000430944 = 5000
        warranty_24000430944 = 20
        acquisition_date_24000430944 = "2018-07-26T12:25:04+05:30"
        warranty_expiry_date_24000430944 = "2018-07-26T12:25:04+05:30"
        domain_24000430944 = "groupo.onmicrosoft.com"
        asset_state_24000430944 = "In Use"
        serial_number_24000430944 = "SW121311334"
        last_audit_date_24000430944 = "2014-07-26T12:25:04+05:30"
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json

$Status = Invoke-RestMethod @Params -Body $body

# Output Response
if ($Status -eq $true) {
    Write-Output "Asset $assetId has been retired/disabled successfully."
} else {
    Write-Output "Failed to retire/disable the asset."
}


I have tried using get method and I was able to get the info of the asset. So I don't believe it is a problem when it comes to the API key. But when I try doing put, it always gives me an error message

The API key is connected to your user according to the documentation. Do you have permission to update this information?
